# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, random, machine-learning

```
import numpy as np

#estimate bias and variance
mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(forest_def,  X_train_gd, y_train_gd, X_test_gd, y_test_gd, loss = 'mse', num_rounds=200, random_seed = 1)


print ('MSE:% .3f'% mse ) 
print ('Sesgo:% .3f'% sesgo1) 
print ('Varianza:% .3f'% var1)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 3
> 4 #estimate bias and variance
> ----> 5 mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(forest_def,  X_train_gd, y_train_gd, X_test_gd, y_test_gd, loss = 'mse', num_rounds=200,
> random_seed = 1)
> 6
> 7
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Hola @Viviana, cuando tengas algún error o duda, haz una pequeña introducción a tu código y el error que sale. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que no sabemos de donde vienen los datos ni nada para poder ayudarte, por lo que has puesto, lo único que puedo ver es que el método:

```
bias_variance_decomp
```

No lo tienes importado, por eso te da error. Ya que está en el módulo mlxtend. Prueba a hacer el import del módulo que corresponde para hacer uso de la función:

```
from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp
```

Recuerda de hacer un pip install del módulo mlxtend.

Un saludo.

Comment: El error que obtiene el OP no es que el método no esté definido, sino que el método no es en realidad una función sino un módulo. Probablemente lo haya importado mal, quizás poniendo `import mlxtend.evaluate as bias_variance_decomp` pero como no muestra esa parte, esto es sólo una hipótesis.

Comment: Hola @abulafia, estoy de acuerdo contigo, no he dicho que no esté definido como tal el método, si no que no lo ha importado. Tampoco podemos ver mucho más del código, porque no tiene declarado ninguno de los argumentos forest_def,  X_train_gd, y_train_gd, X_test_gd, y_test_gd. Pero creo que es una función bias_variance_decomp más que un módulo. Dejo link: http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/bias_variance_decomp/

Comment: Sí, ya te entendí, pero la interpretación correcta del error que aparece es literalmente que `bias_variance_decomp` no es una función sino un módulo y por tanto que no se puede llamar. No se deduce de ese error que no lo haya importado (si no lo hubiera importado de ninguna forma, saldría que el identificador no está definido), sino más bien que lo ha importado incorrectamente. Eso es lo que quería puntualizar. Tu solución es correcta, pero no la explicación de lo que ocurría.

Comment: He tirado por la calle del medio, y me he ido directamente a la solución más que al error como tal porque el módulo está mal importado. Tienes razón en la explicación del error, me centré en la solución. Un saludo.