# como instalar en colab mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp porque aparantenemnet no lo tengo cargado por el error que me emite la corrida

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, python-import

!pip3 install mlxtend
Requirement already satisfied: mlxtend in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.13.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (51.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.20.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (0.22.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlxtend) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0.0->mlxtend) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0.0->mlxtend) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0.0->mlxtend) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib>=3.0.0->mlxtend) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.24.2->mlxtend) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib>=3.0.0->mlxtend) (1.15.0)

from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp

### Requirement already up-to-date: mlxtend in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.18.0)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4
5 #estimate bias and variance
----> 6 mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(forest_def,  X_train_gd, y_train_gd, X_test_gd, y_test_gd, loss = 'mse', num_rounds=200, random_seed = 1)
7
8

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Por favor, considera editar tu pregunta tras leer [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por ejemplo evita que la pregunta sea sólo código (mueve la pregunta del título al interior de la pregunta y pon un título más corto). Formatea correctamente los mensaje de error o los ejemplos de código encerrándolos entre dos líneas con ``` al inicio y al final

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿no es esta pregunta lo mismo que [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/423097/7123) que hiciste antes? ¿No te ha servido la respuesta en aquella?